# Login or Signup With Wechat

Tags: android, authentication, social-networking, access-token, wechat

In my app I have an option to **Login/Signup** with Facebook, Google plus,
**Wechat**, QQchat

Is there any SDK to identify the user details of wechat (like accesstoken or user email) ?

I have found the SDK in their developer site 
which will allow only Sharing to wechat.

But I am looking to fetch user identity.

I am thankful for any kind of answers or suggestions.

Answer (score 4):

You should go to [wechat open platform](https://open.weixin.qq.com/) to register as developer, create an app on the dashboard and then you can use their [OAuth login API](https://open.weixin.qq.com/cgi-bin/showdocument?action=dir_list&t=resource/res_list&verify=1&id=open1419317851&token=5ec1adb2726444ee5bdf37264ad17156e1643463&lang=zh_CN) in their SDK.

Unfortunately, the sdk document is not in English.

Comment: Now, it has English version. Thanks very much. But just a question for web app, does mean "own an approved website app", "approved" = 网站需要通过公安部备案吗？